# Information being uploaded to database even when conditions are false

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a form which gets data from the user via edit boxes and combo boxes, this information then has to be uploaded into a database table so I have to do validation. I did just that and it keeps on saying ''is not a valid integer' yet it is not even supposed to upload anything to the database table as all conditions where not met because of the null check that I did. Did I do my validation wrong?

```
 
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Spin, ExtCtrls,unit7,unit5,unit4, DB, ADODB, Grids, DBGrids,
  pngimage;

type
  Tfrmupload = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    edtname: TEdit;
    edtsurn: TEdit;
    edtidn: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    btnupload: TButton;
    edtmail: TEdit;
    cbprov: TComboBox;
    Image1: TImage;
    cbdiv: TComboBox;
    Label4: TLabel;
    procedure btnuploadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Label7Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmupload: Tfrmupload;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tfrmupload.btnuploadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vname,vsurname,today,c,vidn,vprov,vmail,vdiv:string;
vage,year,i,age:integer;
bnotnull,bIDL,bmail,bage,byoung,valid,idrepeated:boolean;
dt:tdatetime;
begin
vname:=edtname.Text;
vsurname:=edtsurn.Text;
vidn:=edtidn.Text;
vdiv:=cbdiv.Text;
vprov:=cbprov.Text;
vmail:=edtmail.Text;

//booleans
bnotnull:=false;
bIdL:=false;
bmail:=false;
byoung:=false;
idrepeated:=false;
valid:=false;

//check if id entered is not in table already
if unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails.Locate('ID number',vidn,[]) then
begin
  idrepeated:=true;
  showmessage('ID Number already exists');
end;




//null check
if (vname<>'')and(vsurname<>'')and(vidn<>'')and(vprov<>'')and(vmail<>'')and(vdiv<>'') then
begin
  bnotnull:=true;
end
else
begin
  Showmessage('Complete All Fields!');
end;

//get current date
dt:=now;
year:=strtoint(formatdatetime('yyyy',dt));
c:=copy(vidn,1,2);
//calculate age from id number
if (strtoint(c)>=0) and (strtoint(c)<=22) then
begin
age:=year-(2000+strtoint(c));

end
else
begin
  age:=year-(1900+strtoint(c));
end;
//ID length validation
if (length(vidn)=13) then
begin
  bidl:=true;
end;



//check if contestant is not too young
if age<6 then
begin
showmessage('Contestant too young, cannot compete');
byoung:=true;
end;
//check if email is correct format
for i := 1 to length(vmail)do
  begin
    if vmail[i]='@' then
    begin
      bmail:=true;
  end;
  end;
  //error message for email check
  if bmail=false then
  begin
    showmessage('Incorrect Email Format');
  end;

  if bidl=false then
  begin
   showmessage('ID Number must be 13 characters');
  end;

//checks if all the conditions are met and if so we can then upload to database

if (bnotnull=true) and (bidl=true) and (byoung=false)and (bmail=true)and (idrepeated=false) then
begin
 valid:=true;
end;

if valid=true then
begin

unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails.Append;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails['Name(s)']:=vname;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails['Surname']:=vsurname;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails['ID Number']:=vidn;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails['Age']:=age;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails['Province']:=vprov;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails['Email']:=vmail;
unit5.frmadmin.ADODetails.Post;


unit4.frmcontest.ADOLead.Insert;
unit4.frmcontest.ADOLead['ID Number']:=unit4.frmcontest.DBComboID.Text;;
unit4.frmcontest.ADOLead['Name(s)']:=unit4.frmcontest.DBCombonme.Text;
unit4.frmcontest.ADOLead['Division']:=vdiv;

unit4.frmcontest.ADOLead.Post;

showmessage('Details Uploaded');

 frmupload.Hide;
end;


//clears all inputs
edtname.Clear;
edtsurn.Clear;
edtidn.Clear;
cbdiv.Text:='';
cbprov.Text:='';
edtmail.Clear;



end;

procedure Tfrmupload.Label7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
frmupload.Hide;
end;

end.
```

Comment: On which line does it trigger the ''is not a valid integer' message? Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `btnuploadClick` procedure and then use F8 key to step through the procedure.

Comment: Why are you not using DB-aware components?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see a sample database record that was saved to database with false conditions. Beside you can take precaution by applying Trim() function to the input from edit boxes

```
vname:=Trim(edtname.Text);
vsurname:=Trim(edtsurn.Text);
vidn:=Trim(edtidn.Text);
vdiv:=Trim(cbdiv.Text);
vprov:=Trim(cbprov.Text);
vmail:=Trim(edtmail.Text);
```

You may also check the length of variable **vidn**

```
If Length(vidn) < 4 then
//or
If Length(vidn) < 2 then
```

Answer (score -2):

The mistake is pretty obvious. You have strtoint(aka STRING to INT) but you give it a formatted datetime.

```
year:=strtoint(formatdatetime('yyyy',dt));
```

I don't understand why you take the year the way you do it when you can just give the value of 2022 to the integer, but if you insist on doing it that way, you can first format dt, then use **datetimetostr** and then **strtoint**. Another thing which will reduce the code and your work and make everything much more easier is DB-aware components. What they do is, once you connect them to the db and the table and column you're working with, they automatically make updates or inserts. All you need to do is TMSQuery.Insert and then TMSQuery.Post when adding new rows and TMSQuery.Edit and TMSQuery.Post when changing values.

Comment: You say: *The mistake is pretty obvious. You have strtoint(aka STRING to INT) but you give it a formatted datetime.* (Not sure what you mean with "formatted datetime" but) **This is not correct** From help: `function FormatDateTime(const Format: string; DateTime: TDateTime): string;`. As you see it returns a string, in this case (because of the format = 'yyyy') the year as a four-digit string. Using `StrToInt()` is correct because the result is assigned to an `Integer`.